# Cleaner way of calling runnable threads for each audio file

Tags: java, android, multithreading, audio

I have some **working** code, which takes a few buttons and when they are pressed, plays some audio files. However, this code seems uncessearily large and I feel it could be reduced down into smaller methods that could be called. I have, however, taken enough time and effort just to get this working so I can't see how to reduce it. Can you provide a cleaner / smaller and more resuable way of calling audio tracks as this code will only get larger as I intend to have around 30 tracks.

```
    audioBtn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(mediaPlayer != null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
            {
                mProgressStatus = 0;
                mediaPlayer.stop();
                try {
                    mediaPlayer.prepare();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                progressBar1.setProgress(mProgressStatus);
                mHandler.removeCallbacks(runnable1);
                t.interrupt();
                audioBtn2.setEnabled(true);
                audioBtn3.setEnabled(true);
            } else {
                mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.song1);
                mediaPlayer.start();
                t = new Thread(runnable1);
                t.start();
                mProgressStatus = 0;
                progressBar1.setProgress(mProgressStatus);
                audioBtn2.setEnabled(false);
                audioBtn3.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
    });
    audioBtn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(mediaPlayer != null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
            {
                mProgressStatus = 0;
                mediaPlayer.stop();
                try {
                    mediaPlayer.prepare();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                progressBar2.setProgress(mProgressStatus);
                mHandler.removeCallbacks(runnable2);
                t.interrupt();
                audioBtn1.setEnabled(true);
                audioBtn3.setEnabled(true);
            } else {
                mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.song2);
                mediaPlayer.start();
                t = new Thread(runnable2);
                t.start();
                mProgressStatus = 0;
                progressBar2.setProgress(mProgressStatus);
                audioBtn1.setEnabled(false);
                audioBtn3.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
    });
    audioBtn3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(mediaPlayer != null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
            {
                mProgressStatus = 0;
                mediaPlayer.stop();
                try {
                    mediaPlayer.prepare();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                progressBar3.setProgress(mProgressStatus);
                mHandler.removeCallbacks(runnable3);
                t.interrupt();
                audioBtn1.setEnabled(true);
                audioBtn2.setEnabled(true);
            } else {
                mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.song3);
                mediaPlayer.start();
                t = new Thread(runnable3);
                t.start();
                mProgressStatus = 0;
                progressBar3.setProgress(mProgressStatus);
                audioBtn1.setEnabled(false);
                audioBtn2.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
    });
}

private Runnable runnable1 = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (mProgressStatus < 30) {
                mProgressStatus++;
                mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        progressBar1.setProgress(mProgressStatus);
                    }
                });
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            mProgressStatus = 0;
            mHandler.removeCallbacks(runnable1);
        }
    }
};
private Runnable runnable2 = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (mProgressStatus < 30) {
                mProgressStatus++;
                mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        progressBar2.setProgress(mProgressStatus);
                    }
                });
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            mProgressStatus = 0;
            mHandler.removeCallbacks(runnable2);
        }
    }
};
private Runnable runnable3 = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (mProgressStatus < 30) {
                mProgressStatus++;
                mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        progressBar3.setProgress(mProgressStatus);
                    }
                });
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            mProgressStatus = 0;
            mHandler.removeCallbacks(runnable3);
        }
    }
};
```

One thing I've already looked at is moving the setting of buttons to enabled/disabled to a separate class, but that involves creating more large un-resuable scripts to handle calling the main thread (As I need to reset the buttons in the runnable threads after songs have finished)

I'm also not sure if it's possible to pass element ids as arguments to functions, in which case that would help reduce the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce duplicate codes by defining an abstract `OnClickListener` class and delegate the responsibility of the "different" parts to whoever extends it. *You can of course define this as an Inner Class to access the parameters of the current class.* this is called [Template method pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern)

first define **MyClickListener**:

```
public abstract class MyClickListener extends View.OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(mediaPlayer != null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
        {
            mProgressStatus = 0;
            mediaPlayer.stop();
            try {
                mediaPlayer.prepare();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            setProgress(mProgressStatus);
            mHandler.removeCallbacks(runnable1);
            t.interrupt();
            enableButtons(true);
        } else {
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.song1);
            mediaPlayer.start();
            t = getThread();
            t.start();
            mProgressStatus = 0;
            setProgress(mProgressStatus);
            enableButtons(false);
        }
    }

   public abstract void setProgress(int progress);
   public abstract void enableButtons(boolean enable);
   public abstract Thread getThread();
}
```

then use it like this:

```
audioBtn1.setOnClickListener(new MyClickListener(){        
   public abstract void setProgress(int progress){
        progressBar1.setProgress(progress);
   }
   public abstract void enableButtons(boolean enable){
        audioBtn2.setEnabled(enable);
        audioBtn3.setEnabled(enable);
   }
   public abstract Thread getThread(){
        return new Thread(runnable1);;
   }
})
```

And so on for other buttons.
You can apply this pattern for the runnables too!